# Deleting cPanel FTP account via PHP

Tags: php, ftp, cpanel

I have a script that creates a cpanel FTP account like so:

```
$url = "https://$user:$pass@$domain:2083/frontend/$skin/ftp/doaddftp.html?";
$url = $url . "login=$fuser&password=$fpass&homedir=$fhomedir&quota=$fquota";
$result = @file_get_contents($url);
```

I am trying to find out what the URL would be to delete the FTP account. I see the "doaddftp.html" and GET parameters. I assume there is a similar way to remove an FTP account.

Anyone know what the URL would be?

Comment: Try deleting a user in cPanel and check the request that gets sent?

Comment: I tried viewing the page source and everything but I can't find the page that the "remove" button links to

Comment: Try using a packet sniffer like Charles or Wireshark to check the outgoing request when you click the delete button. The 'Network' tab in Chrome Inspector or Firebug should do the job too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following link will be useful for you

[http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/ApiDocs/Api2/ApiFtp#Ftp::delftp](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/ApiDocs/Api2/ApiFtp#Ftp%3a%3adelftp)

Note:Delete an FTP account. This function is only available in cPanel 11.27.x and later.

Answer (score 0):

This would work:

```
$buildRequest = '/execute/Ftp/delete_ftp?user='.$username.'&destroy=0'; # To remove the home directory of the ftp acc change to 1

$openSocket = fsockopen('localhost',2082);
if(!$openSocket) {
    return "Socket error";
    exit();
}

$authString = $cPanelUser . ":" . $cPanelPass;
$authPass = base64_encode($authString);
$buildHeaders  = "GET " . $buildRequest ."\r\n";
$buildHeaders .= "HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$buildHeaders .= "Host:localhost\r\n";
$buildHeaders .= "Authorization: Basic " . $authPass . "\r\n";
$buildHeaders .= "\r\n";

fputs($openSocket, $buildHeaders);
while(!feof($openSocket)) {
    fgets($openSocket,128);
}
fclose($openSocket);
```